# User "client" cannot create replicationcontrollers in the namespace "default"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

On trying to create a replication controller on a cluster in GKE using terraform, I get this error:

```
kubernetes_replication_controller.k8_pod: Failed to create replication controller: replicationcontrollers is forbidden: User "client" cannot create replicationcontrollers in the namespace "default"
```

I have `kubectl` configured and have tested it by creating pods/replication controllers on google kubernetes engine. I have also tried to use
`gcloud config unset container/use_client_certificate` as some resources suggest:
 [Resource 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49208249/6373131) [Resource 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/vuPUGlL6At4)

The resource provisioning code sample is as follows:

```
resource "kubernetes_replication_controller" "k8_pod" {
    metadata {
        name = "testing-deployment"
        labels {
            App = "wassup"
        }
    }

    spec {
        selector {
            App = "wassup"
        }

        template {
            container {
                image = "image/name/here"
                name  = "testing-deployment"

                port {
                    container_port = 8080
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the user 'client' needs to be given the role to create replication controllers - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please? I am using the [google-container-cluster](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html) to create the cluster and [kubernetes-replication-controller](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/replication_controller.html) to set up this configuration.
I am trying to avoid any manual steps. Ideally `terraform apply "tfplan"` should configure the resource as wanted.

Comment: That "client" user is a the account that terraform is trying to use to create the replication controller. It could be a terraform bug as seems very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127339/how-to-use-terraform-kubernetes-provider-with-eks I'm assuming that's the full error and you aren't getting 'unknown user' on the end like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075723/what-does-unknown-user-client-mean