# Terraform enable EKS cluster access for other IAM users

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to set up a EKS cluster, enabling other IAM users to connect and tinker with the cluster. To do so, [AWS recommends patching a config map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html), which I did. Now I want to enable the same “feature” using terraform.

I use terraforms EKS provider and read [in the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest#general-notes) in section "Due to the plethora of tooling a..." that basically authentication is up to myself.

Now I use the [Terraform Kubernetes provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs) to update this config map:

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
  depends_on = [module.eks.cluster_id]
  metadata {
    name      = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  data = THATS_MY_UPDATED_CONFIG
}
```

But do not succeed and get the following error:

```
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: 2022/01/07 15:49:55 [DEBUG] Kubernetes API Response Details:
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: HTTP/2.0 409 Conflict
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: Content-Length: 206
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: Audit-Id: 15....
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: Cache-Control: no-cache, private
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: Content-Type: application/json
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: Date: Fri, 07 Jan 2022 14:49:55 GMT
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid: f43...
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid: 0054...
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: {
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:  "kind": "Status",
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:  "apiVersion": "v1",
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:  "metadata": {},
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:  "status": "Failure",
2022-01-07T15:49:55.732+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:  "message": "configmaps \"aws-auth\" already exists",
2022-01-07T15:49:55.733+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:  "reason": "AlreadyExists",
2022-01-07T15:49:55.733+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:  "details": {
2022-01-07T15:49:55.733+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:   "name": "aws-auth",
2022-01-07T15:49:55.733+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:   "kind": "configmaps"
2022-01-07T15:49:55.733+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:  },
2022-01-07T15:49:55.733+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:  "code": 409
2022-01-07T15:49:55.733+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: }
2022-01-07T15:49:55.733+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5:
2022-01-07T15:49:55.733+0100 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-kubernetes_v2.7.1_x5: -----------------------------------------------------
2022-01-07T15:49:55.775+0100 [ERROR] vertex "module.main.module.eks.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth" error: configmaps "aws-auth" already exists
╷
│ Error: configmaps "aws-auth" already exists
│
│   with module.main.module.eks.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth,
│   on ../../modules/eks/eks-iam-map-users.tf line 44, in resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth":
│   44: resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
│
╵
```

It seems this is a controversial problem and as everyone using EKS and Terraform should have it – I ask myself how to solve this? The [related issue](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/852), [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127339/terraform-kubernetes-provider-with-eks-fails-on-configmap) is close .... I'm somewhat lost, anyone has an idea?

I use the following versions:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    # https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.70"
    }

    # https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "~> 2.7.1"
    }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.2"
}

...
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "18.0.3"
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use 17.24.0 and have no idea what is new with 18.0.3.

In my case, I follow this example:
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v17.24.0/examples/complete/main.tf

My main.tf

```
locals {
  eks_map_roles       = []
  eks_map_users       = []
}

data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority[0].data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
}

module "eks" {
  source = "..."
  ...
  eks_map_roles       = local.eks_map_roles
  eks_map_users       = local.eks_map_users
  ...
}
```

To add another user, you can follow this docs: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error/

I think you should add the role (don't forget to remove the path).

Comment: sounds like a workaround but shouldn't it work with the latest version as well?

Comment: @lony It's not a workaround, please read the example on github carefully. Normally, I will not use a new version like 18 for eks module because of stability, and upgrading/downgrading the module version is not an easy task.

Comment: you are right—I yesterday "backported" to the version you proposed and a voilà the thing worked like expected... coming from self coded CloudFormation or boto3 scripts I'm a bit disappointed with terraforms stability. If like you described, you have to back check if a new version works as expected. So learned my lesson and problem solved - thanks to you!

Comment: There are some problems with 17.24.0 like the dependency of "managed aws-auth" when set create_eks is false and list type in worker groups. I think they will fix in 18.x

Answer (score 0):

map_users is deprecated in v18.x of [eks module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/UPGRADE-18.0.md):

```
Support for managing aws-auth configmap has been removed. This change also removes the dependency on the Kubernetes Terraform provider, the local dependency on aws-iam-authenticator for users, as well as the reliance on the forked http provider to wait and poll on cluster creation. To aid users in this change, an output variable aws_auth_configmap_yaml has been provided which renders the aws-auth configmap necessary to support at least the IAM roles used by the module (additional mapRoles/mapUsers definitions to be provided by users)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: nope they readded it https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/compare/v18.19.0...v18.20.0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are allowing the EKS module to create a ConfigMap for you which IMO is recommended as it allows you to manipulate the aws_auth configmap independently.

Create a locals variable as shown below which is first pulling the default aws_auth configmap that the Terraform EKS module is creating.
Then add the rolearn and groups mapping as needed.

```
locals {

  # Creating the AWS-AUTH
  aws_auth_configmap_yaml = <<-EOT
  ${chomp(module.eks.aws_auth_configmap_yaml)}
      - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.id}:role/RoleName
        username: admin
        groups:
          - system:masters
  EOT

}
```

and then create a kubectl_manifest resource using https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "aws_auth" {
  yaml_body = <<YAML
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Terraform
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
${local.aws_auth_configmap_yaml}
YAML

  depends_on = [module.eks]

}
```

Comment: So I basically manually adjust the config map after the cluster creation? Do you know why this is no longer possible directly from the module?

Comment: the newer modules allows they had removed support earlier but brought it back https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/compare/v18.19.0...v18.20.0